# How to share $request variable between other function from other url in same controller on laravel

Tags: laravel

### **I want to share $request variable between other function from other url in same controller on laravel like below but how ?**

*Controller*

```
class ABCController extends Controller
{

    public function validation(Request $request)
    {
          ---------------
    }

     public function save()
    {
          Log::debug($request)
    }
```

*api.php*

```
Route::post('/abc',[ABCController::class,'validation']);

Route::get('/save',[ABCController::class,'save']);
```

### What I tried

```
class ABCController extends Controller
{

    public function validation(Request $request)
    {
          Session::put('data', $request)
          session(['data' => $request]);

          Log::debug(Session::get('data'));
          Log::debug(session('data'));
    }

     public function save()
    {
          Log::debug(Session::get('data'));
          Log::debug(session('data'));
    }
```

I tried above but Log::debug in save function show me null in log.

Please give me advice.

Comment: What you are trying to do seems wrong, i would not rely on serialization of the request between calls. Same if you call these urls in postman there is no session. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I want  to email verify without laravels, so velify request and send mail which have code in first function , In next function verify code and save data but I dont wanna valify request twice.. So I wanna keep $request.

Comment: Imo you should not try to keep request data between two request, if you need it, add it to the link they are clicking for it

Answer (score 0):

Create a global variable

```
 class ABCController extends Controller
{
private $data;

public function validation(Request $request)
{
      $this->data =$request;
}

 public function save()
{
      echo $this->data;
}
}
```